# Search for text string in item name and paste assigned number in other cell

Tags: excel, string, vba, search, copy-paste

I have a 7000 row spreadsheet that certain colors are assigned a number
I need a search string to find a specific color of the item in the E column and paste the assigned number in the F cell next to it.

The item names are way longer as are the assigned number but for all intensive purposes, the result is the same.  The numbers are on another sheet but I can insert a column and paste them

Thanks

[Search for String and apply its code to next cell pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0MRq.jpg)

Comment: You can use the Range.Find method which returns a range if found or nothing if not or the Instr function which returns an integer signifying the position where the string was found or 0 if it's not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use Autofilter to achieve the desired output.
You may try something like this...

```
Sub InsertColorCode()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
Dim x
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
lr1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
x = Range("A3:B" & lr1).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    With ws.Range("E2:E" & lr2)
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & x(i, 2) & "*"
        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
            ws.Range("E3:E" & lr2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(0, 1).Value = x(i, 1)
        End If
    End With
Next i
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```